# Export multiple Excel file using ClosedXML

Tags: c#

I created a function to generate Excel using ClosedXML.Excel.it is working when i generate one Excel. Now, i would like to generate double excel in same function but not work. anybody could give an adivse?thanks

```
public FileResult Export()
    {
        DataTable test = new DataTable("test");
        test.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[] {new DataColumn("Name")});

        foreach (var record in recordtest)
        {
             test.Rows.Add(record.name);
        }
     
        using (XLWorkbook ts = new XLWorkbook())
        {
              var testSheet = ts.Worksheets.Add(test);
              testSheet.Cell("D4").Value = "First Name";
              testSheet.Range("A4:A5").Merge();              
              testSheet.Range("A4:Q5").Columns().Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = 
XLColor.Almond;
        }
        using (MemoryStream steam = new MemoryStream())
        {
               wb.SaveAs(steam);
               var fileName = String.Format("{0}-{1}.xlsx", "test", 
                   DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
               return File(steam.ToArray(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats- 
                officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", fileName);
         }
     }
```

Comment: `double` excel? do you mean to say two excel files? if yes, can you show us code to which generates two excel files? Also add error which you are getting while saving second excel file

Comment: Hi@PrasadTelkikar, thank you for your reply, yes , i want to generate two excel, i have copy and paste the above same code 2 time for generate 2 excel , but not working.

Comment: have you tried by adding two different names while saving the file?. Right now your code is trying to save both the files with the same name.

`var fileName = String.Format("{0}-{1}.xlsx", "test", 
                    DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHH:mm:ss"));`

Comment: yesyes, i have added two differemt names, "test1" and "test2"

Comment: Did it work after giving two different names?

Comment: not work..../3\